# Strange touch behaviour

Tags: android, touch

I've stumbled upon a strange behaviour that occours only on Galaxy S5 mini.

Let's say my app have two image views (ivA and ivB) and a small empty space between them like this

```
+------------+---+--------------+
|            |   |              |
| ivA        |   |  ivB         |
|            |   |              |
+------------+---+--------------+
```

and i've set onTouchListener for both like this

```
    ivA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();
            int idx = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());

            Log.i(TAG, "PRESSED ivA: " + action + " - IDX " + idx);
        }
    }
```

Then i do these moves:

- with left thumb i press ivA (and keep it pressed)
- with right thumb i press ivB

what i expect:

- get a ACTION_DOWN event on ivA (pointer id 0), then get an ACTION_DOWN on ivB (pointer id 1)

what i got:

- get an ACTION_DOWN event on ivA (pointer id 0) then i get an ACTION_MOVE event on ivA (pointer id 0)

I guess the touch screen driver thinks the left finger is moving toward right instead of detect a second touch by a second finger.

Is it a problem fixable by updating my software in your opinion?

*Update: 
I forgot to say that i tried to expand the empty space between ivA and ivB and it works as expected. If the two clicks are distant enough, the driver doesn't mess.*

Comment: Not sure whether this is actually relevant for the functionality, but have you tried adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>` to the manifest?

Comment: I've included it. Multitouch works correctly if the two ImageViews are distant enough (i've updated the question)

Comment: @DavideBerra any luck? I would love to hear if you have got a solution

Comment: so far... no :( i'll put a bounty on it @Max

Comment: `I guess the touch screen driver thinks the left finger is moving toward right instead of detect a second touch by a second finger` Not sure about this. `ACTION_CANCEL` should have been dispatched in that case, because second touch is outside of the bound os first `ImageView`.

Comment: Maybe device screen is slightly damaged, check out on another (similar) device if this problem occurs, or You can place buttons in multiple position (top, bottom, left, right) and check if it working here as expected or not

Comment: @Wrobel the problem occours on two different S5 minis. I'm guessing if i can do some kind of workaround to avoid this behaviour

Comment: You could enable the Show Pointer Location option in the Developer Options and see how the device is reacting to all touches from when you touched till when you removed your finger. If your not seeing two distinct trances for both of your fingers on both devices, then probably the S5 mini has a bug.

Comment: Even i faced a problem in Sansung S8 that there is a space between two items like when i am taking a grid layout inside a recycler view there is some space between the grid items huge spaces, which is not occurring in any other device, even with devices with larger screens, i am not getting a solution , anyone help would very help ful